Combining rotation about 2 axes of a parallelopiped brick
[This type of question does have few similar ones in mathematics exchange but those are mainly expressed in terms of vector or quaternions (which I have no idea of) but I am seeking more of a help in visualizing the actual motion so thought this forum would be the perfect one for that]
lets assume that we have a brick which has its length and breadth along the $xy$-plane. Now if we are to rotate it about $z$-axis and $y$-axis simultaneously, then how would that motion be to visualize? [I have no idea of simulating this scenario. so if there is any sort of simulator of such, kindly do let me know that would be of great help]
I faced this problem while studying Stokes' theorem. Well this might sound a bit absurd since they don't seem to align much but let me elaborate.
Stokes' theorem gives us the idea that $\int{\overrightarrow{\rm \nabla}\times\overrightarrow{\rm A}\bullet \overrightarrow{\rm dS}}$ informs us of the rotation of the entire surface. But curl of the vector at any point gives us the magnitude and direction of maximum rotation of an infinitesimal surface containing that point oriented in the direction of maximum rotation. However we do not know whether $\overrightarrow{\rm dS}$ directs to that specific direction or not. This is where dot product comes in play which gives us the component of curl along the direction of $\overrightarrow{\rm dS}$. But what happens to the another component of that maximum rotation thing? [I may not be able to express completely what I understood or I might have misunderstood either way any answer would help me immensely]


Now if we are to rotate it about z-axis and y-axis simultaneously

As far as I can understand, this means to rotate around an axis parallel to yz plane.

This is where dot product comes in play which gives us the component
of curl along the direction of dS

One physical example of Stokes theorem can be seen in this question.
There is a density of current $\vec j$ at every point of the wire of the coil, and pointing along the wire at that point. The Ampère differential law states that:$\nabla \times \vec B = \mu_0 \vec j$. Integrating both sides along the plane defined by the red ring around the coil:$$\int_S (\nabla \times \vec B) \cdot \vec n \,dS = \mu_0\int_S \vec j \cdot \vec n \,dS$$ And applying Stokes theorem to the LHS we get information on the tangential component of the magnetic field along the ring that encloses the plane:$$\oint \vec B \cdot \,\vec dl = \mu_0\int_S \vec j \cdot \vec n \,dS = \mu_0 I$$ where $I$ is the current crossing the plane.
Only the components of the "sources of $\vec B$" (all the $\vec j$'s) orthogonal to the plane contributes to the $\vec B$ at the red ring. In order to see the effects of the other components, we need the 2 others mutually orthogonal planes, and their respective boundary rings.

about the rotation, vectorially we can understand that the axis would be parallel to yz plane. But I wanted to know the orientation of the brick or in short I want to visualize that motion
